# See which methods dont have unit test on intelj idea

Tags: intellij-idea, code-coverage

When I turn to project view, I can see percentages for a single class.

When I go inside, i cant see which methods are covered.

When i take export of results, and open in browser for `HTML`, I can see some green and red lines.

I can understand if a method has red or does not have any green, it does not have unit test.

But this is hard way.

Are there better ways here? Like: how can i find the unit test of a method if it has an unit test?

Comment: I tried to make your question easier to understand, please review my changes. Beyond that: it *might* be helpful if you *carefully* add some smaller screen shots to better explain what you are doing. You should also add what kind of code coverage you are running, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Answering on *how can i find the unit test of a method if it has an unit test*?

I think there is a misconception on your end. Nothing says that there is exactly **one** (or zero) unit test for a specific method.

It is rather common that there are *multiple* tests per production code method. For example to test the different results for different cases of input parameters.

It is also possible that a production code method gets executed when some "unrelated" test runs.

From that point of view, the "best" what you can do: select the production code method and have IntelliJ show you its [usages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-usages-in-project.html). IntelliJ tells you in which module usages are found, and obviously: if the usage is within your unit test module, you know for sure: the  method is used in the tests listed there.

But as said: that doesn't mean that other tests aren't running that method when doing their specific testing.